# how to move a contact to block/spam list in android

Tags: android, block, contacts, android-contacts, spam

I want to move contacts added by my application to block/spam list, so that user will not see notification and sound when SMS comes from that contact no.

I'm able to add contact to phone but not able to move that contact to block/spam list.

[Truecaller application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.truecaller&hl=en)  does the same thing.

Can someone please give some reference about this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the `SEND_TO_VOICEMAIL` field on the [ContactsContract.Contacts](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html) table:

```
long contactId = <your contact id>;
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
ContentProviderOperation update = ContentProviderOperation
            .newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withSelection(Data.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId, null)
            .withValue(Contacts.SEND_TO_VOICEMAIL , 1)
            .build();
update.apply(contentResolver, null, 0);
```

Comment: thanks for your response. But I'm not able to try this code as 1. what will be contactId, how can I get it and 2. contentProvider, how to initialize that? Can you please post the code in a more details? It will help me a lot

Comment: you wrote `I want to move contacts added by my application`, I assume you at least have the contact-id for contacts you just created. Regarding `ContentProvider`, it's a typo, I meant `ContentResolver`, I've updated to answer on how to get it (assuming you're in an activity)